# error accessing external endpoint kubernetes in digital ocean

Tags: kubernetes, devops, digital-ocean, webapi

I deployed a .NET WEB API application to Kubernets, however, when I try to access the external endpoint provided by LoadBalancer, nothing returns, do I need to configure anything else? Can anyone help me?

my configuration;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: car-companie-deployment
  labels:
    app: car-companie-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: car-companie-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: car-companie-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: car-companie-container
        image: <IMAGE>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: car-companie-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: car-companie-deployment
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

images pods and kuberents :
https://imgur.com/a/N1esvEd

I tried configuring nginx, it was the closest I could get to completing the communication with the pod, but it resulted in errors 1024 worker_connections are not enough